# Linux: what prevents us from reading the memory from code segment?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, segmentation-fault, paging

I wrote a simple code trying to find out if we can read and print the memory in code segment:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
  int *code_ptr = 0x4;
  printf("code_ptr = %x\n", code_ptr);
  printf("*code_ptr = %x\n", *code_ptr);
}
```

My system is x86_64 + Ubuntu 19.04 (Disco Dingo). And the program failed with the following output:

```
code_ptr = 4
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

IIUC, in Linux, the code segment and data segment share the same base address. And if that's true, this program will read the memory in code segement, and I was expecting that there won't be any crash since `0x04` should be in the range of data segment (which starts at the beginning). And this should pass the paging check since the mapped memory for the code segment is read-only and we only read the memory here.

So did I miss anything or is there any other mechanisms that prevent us from reading from this `%ds:0x4`?

Comment: Why do you assume that address 0x00000004 belongs to your process? Most probably, it won't.

Comment: I think this 0x4 is a logical address, not a physical address. And for a 64 bit system, the logical addresses from 0 to 2^64 -1 all belong to the current process. And this logical address will first be translated to linear address with `%ds:0x4`, which I think is 0x4. And then by referring to the page table, it will finally be mapped to a physical address.

Comment: *"what prevents us from reading the memory from code segment?"* -- Nothing, assuming you know where it is.  Your program is getting a seg fault because the virtual memory at 0x4 is simply not mapped to a valid physical address.  Same thing, i.e. a seg fault,  would happen with an invalid data section address.  Try obtaining a linker map to get an idea where the various sections are.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38961649/gcc-how-to-create-a-mapfile-of-the-object-file

Comment: Why not try the GNU debugger **gdb** on your program to see what memory locations the instructions occupy?   If  **gdb** can *disassemble* the machine instructions, then that memory must be readable.

Comment: The first page of virtual memory addresses from 0 is usually left unmapped in order to catch null pointer dereferencing errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your key misunderstanding is that you're assuming the 8086 hardware feature called "the data segment" is the same as the executable image subdivision also called "the data segment." [Xenix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xenix) may have used that hardware feature that way, but no modern x86 Unix does. On a modern Unix, `%ds:0` always points to linear address zero, not to the beginning of the executable's data segment. (And similarly `%cs:0` points to linear address zero, not to the executable's text segment.)

All of an executable's segments will be loaded into linear address space somewhere *well above* linear address 0, and on current-generation OSes the load addresses will be randomized on each run.

There's no standard way to get a pointer to the beginning of the executable's code or data segment. On GNU systems you can use [`dl_iterate_phdr`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dl_iterate_phdr), and other OSes may have similar functionality under a different name.

Comment: what about printing the address of `main()` ?

Comment: @Yvain The address of `main` will be inside the executable's text segment, but probably not at the beginning of it.

Comment: @zwol *"... inside the executable's text segment"* -- Don't you mean the text *section*?

Comment: @sawdust No, I mean segment. ELF has both; to first order, sections are used in unlinked object files, segments are used in executables and shared objects.

Comment: Thanks @zwol! Yea, my main misunderstanding is that I'm assuming the program starts from linear address 0. And I've tried and confirmed that the program will start from different linear addresses upon each execution.